# Rewrite/Redirect rule in IIS causing trailing slash

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using 3 domain-agnostic rewrite rules in my IIS. First i redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, then i redirect from naked-domain to www and in the end i remove .php from the URL by rewrite.

However, i see that whenever i access a page which is a subfolder and i access the index page in it, a trailing slash is added in the end of the url. Example:

Root -> subfolder called Items with an index.php in it

URL - www.xxx.net/items/

If i access a file other than index.php inside that folder it doesn't have a trailing slash

Root -> subfolder called Items with 2.php in it

URL - www.xxx.net/items/2

Normally, i wouldn't care but i noticed that google and the crawlers consider www.xxx.net/items and www.xxx.net/items/ as different entities which causes issues.

I know it's something easy but can't pinpoint it right now. Can someone show me how to get rid of this behaviour?

Here are the rules:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
               <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                     <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="Redirect naked domain to www" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="(.*)" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="Remove PHP" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)$" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
               </rule>
            </rules>
         </rewrite>
```

Comment: Enable FRT to see more details, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: hmm did exactly as it said in the article and they won't generate. I will look into it

Comment: @Djongov Please enable log via Failed request tracing->edit site tracing..->Enable. Your rule shouldn't add trailing slash. Plesae check whether the trailing slash was added by web browser. If it is added by IIS, the FRT log should show the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot about it, it turns out that this is very expected behaviour and you need to factor it in. Basically when you know that you going to get a trailing slash, make sure that your links pointing to this page also include trailing slash in the end so you don't get a redirect.